# PHP/MySQL - HTML Form Text Area Query (query each line in form)

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I am needing a way for a user to paste data into a textarea in a form
and query each line individually.

For example - let's say that a user needs to get the age of each person
from the db. Instead of doing it 1 name at a time - the user pastes in
10 names.

name1
name2
name3 etc.

Then the user submits the form and the php output is:

name1 | 43
name2 | 21
name3 | 17, etc.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

---

```
<?php

//dbstuff:


$connection = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die (mysql_errno().": ".mysql_error()."<BR>");
mysql_select_db($dbname);

$list = explode("\r\n", htmlentities($_POST['name'])); // 'names' is the name of your textarea; I use htmlentities to help sanitize the data; $list is now an array of the entries split by a new line character
foreach($list as $l){
    $name = $l;
    //query the DB
    $query= "select peg_site_id, fa_code from cpm where peg_site_id='". $name."'";
}

//DEBUG
$debug = 1; //Select 1 for ON, or 2 for OFF
if ($debug == 1){
echo "<br /><br />START DEBUG<br />" . "*********************************<br />" . $query. "<br /><br />" . $count_query. "<br /><br />" . "*********************************<br />" . "END DEBUG<br />";
}
else {
echo "";
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
h4 {font-family: sans-serif}
p {font-family: courier}
p.sansserif {font-family: sans-serif}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php

// Print out result

$result= mysql_query($query);
$num_results = mysql_num_rows($result);

for ($i=0; $i <$num_results; $i++)
{

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo "<b>Customer Site ID:</b> ".$row['fa_code'] . "   <b>Site ID:</b> ".$row['peg_site_id'] . "</br>";


//echo "--------------------------------------------------------";
//echo "</br></br>";

}

?> 
</font>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you're going to take the form input and split it into separate entities and then run your query on each entity. For example:

```
$list = explode("\r\n", htmlentities($_POST['names'])); // 'names' is the name of your textarea; I use htmlentities to help sanitize the data; $list is now an array of the entries split by a new line character
foreach($list as $l){
    $name = $l;
    //query the DB  
}
```

Is that the gist of what you're looking for?

**EDIT**
You're only receiving the last because you're only doing the query on the last. The method which you're doing this seems a little odd. When I inserted `//query the DB`, I really meant, at that point query the DB; not create the query statement to run later. What you're doing by using

```
$query= "select peg_site_id, fa_code from cpm where peg_site_id='". $name."'";
```

is re-creating the variable `$query` every time you loop. So the `$query` variable will only ever have one entry in it. `$num_results` will only ever be one. I'd suggest something like this:

```
$html = '';
foreach($list as $l){
    $name = $l;
    //query the DB
    $query= "select peg_site_id, fa_code from cpm where peg_site_id='".     $name."'";
    $result= mysql_query($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $html .= "<b>Customer Site ID:</b> ".$row['fa_code'] . "   <b>Site ID:</b> ".$row['peg_site_id'] . "</br>";
}
echo $html;
```

You'll notice I create the `$html` variable, add to it the results from the query integrated with the HTML formatting that I want, and then I `echo` it all out at one time. Hope that helps!

P.S. As a side note, I use `PDO` to query the DB as `mysql_` has been deprecated. I'd highly and strongly suggest switching to using the `mysqli_` or `PDO` methods instead of the `mysql_` method.

Comment: Thank you...this is what I am getting. I am only seeing the very last line showing up in the query.

START DEBUG
*********************************
select name, age from x where name='bob smith'



*********************************
END DEBUG
Result: Age: 42 Name: Bob Smith

Comment: added my code to the original post...thanks...any help is appreciated!

Comment: @user2680315 I've edited my code based on your edits. Please review.

Comment: That did it! Thank you very much!

Comment: Just a followup question...what if a user searches for 'Bob' and there are multiple rows for 'Bob'. Right now with the code - it will only output the last row. I have tried a while loop - but I am missing something...thanks.

Comment: @user2680315 I'm looking at the php docs for the `mysql` class and I don't see a function that will do what you need: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php. Basically, you need a way to fetch all the matching rows and not just the first row that matches. The `mysqli` and `PDO` classes have this ability: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php & http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php. It may be best to switch to a class that isn't deprecated before you go much further.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your string from the textarea using the function **explode** in PHP. After splitting your string you will iterate the result array and query the database. See the **explode** documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: If you're going to reference PHP.net, please use English-based links. http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php and not http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php